# Opencv Grayscale images

Tags: java, android, opencv

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    inputFrame.gray();
}
```

This returns a mat. If i convert this to a byte array the maximum is 127 and minimum is -128. I want to convert this to min 0 and max 255. Is this possible???

If so how?
I tried to write a `for` loop and added 128 to each element in byte array. Though it causes the byte array to have min of -105 and max of 107.

Any ideas??

```
for(int k=0;k<grayScaleImageArray.length;++k){
        grayScaleImageArray[k]= (byte) (grayScaleImageArray[k]+128);
    }
```

Comment: if grayScaleImageArray is 8 bit signed type you can't store values > 127 there. Create an 8 bit unsigned array and store the shifted values there.

Answer (score 0):

As Micka stated in the comments, you have to use a different typ i.e. 8 bit unsigned.

```
uchar[] unsignedArray = new uchar[signedArray.length];
for(int k = 0; k < signedArray.length; ++k)
{
  unsignedArray[k] = uchar((int)(signedArray[k]) + 128);
}
```